# firmar documento xml con xmlsec1

Tags: xml, firma-digital

genero un documento xml y agrego los tags necesarios para la firma de dicho documento:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"></CanonicalizationMethod>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"></Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
<DigestValue></DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue></SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus></Modulus>
<Exponent></Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate></X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

para firmalo utilizo el siguiente comando :

```
xmlsec1 --sign --output docfirmado.xml --pkcs12 elcertificado.pfx --pwd laclavedelcert --id-attr:URI Reference eldocafirmar.xml
```

y completa los tags pero necesito que en el tag referece aparezca el calor del atributo URI.
el cual debiese quedar

```
<Reference URI="#ACDE12">
```

pero me queda vacio

```
<Reference URI="">
```

que debo hacer para que el atributo URI del tag referencia quede con el valor?, gracias.